# Create animated gif from multiple HTML pages using command line

Tags: linux, qt, image-processing, command-line

Ok this could be a complicated one. After advice as much as anything else. I'd like to create one script which i can run from a command line which will take a list of HTML pages and converts them into an animated gif (in the order that I provide them). Speed is a consideration, but at this stage any ideas however long winded are welcome.

For test purposes my HTML pages are:

- http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport
- http://www.bbc.co.uk/news
- http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do mean to render the pages in a browser first as they are captured?

(Edit: From comments, apparently not) 
Have a look at http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html
I couldn't get it to work with your pages, but I *think* you could.
It worked fine with other sites (Like stackexchange). 
Also, sometimes the BBC gets a bit funny about requests from Australia...

I downloaded the 64bit Linux version, un-tarred it, and tried with this super-basic script.

*hello.js*

```
console.log('Start ...');

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I started it with options to run the debugger (viewable in Chrome) but I bailed out after that.

```
phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 --remote-debugger-autorun=yes hello.js
```

I'll leave the original answer up here for the benifit of people who might want to do this on a desktop, as well as for the animated gif conversion.

For a capture from a GUI desktop:

- Capture screenshots from the command line
- Remote control the browser
- Process the images

Then it would be about getting the timing right in the script. Though "speed is a consideration", are we talking seconds or minutes?

A roughie example:
install '[scrot](http://freecode.com/projects/scrot)' as a screen grabber

```
apt-get install scrot
```

[imagemagick / convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#gif_anim) may already be installed?

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

maximise your default browser

run this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from subprocess import Popen


wobpages = ['http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport','http://www.bbc.co.uk/news','http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather']
x =1
for page in wobpages:
    Popen(["xdg-open", page])
    time.sleep(8)
    img = 'wobpage%s.png' % x
    Popen(["scrot", img])
    x += 1
opt = "convert -delay 100 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif"
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', opt])
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a go and get back to you. The only issue I forsee is that 'maximise your default browser' - I don't have access to a GUI so the browser would need to be headless.